# I have a CSV file. From this I have to create Histogram and do linear regression on it

Tags: python, csv, histogram, linear-regression

For my assignment, I have a CSV file.

```
Row ID  Product Name    Product Price   Monthly Sales   Shipping Type   Geographic region   No Of Customer Who Bought the Product   Customer Type
1   Bush Somerset Collection Bookcase   261.96  1047.84 Free    Hooker Creek    2   old
2   Hon Deluxe Fabric Upholstered Stacking Chairs, Rounded Back 731.94  4391.64 Free    Mount Hotham    3   old
3   Bretford CR4500 Series Slim Rectangular Table   957.5775    9575.775    Paid    Hughenden   5   new
4   Eldon Expressions Wood and Plastic Desk Accessories, Cherry Wood    48.86   684.04  Paid    Julia Creek 7   new
5   Chromcraft Rectangular Conference Tables    1706.184    30711.312   Paid    Kalbarri    9   new
6   Global Deluxe Stacking Chair, Gray  71.372  285.488 Free    King Island 2   old
7   Bretford CR4500 Series Slim Rectangular Table   1044.63 6267.78 Paid    Kalkgurung  3   new
8   Riverside Palais Royal Lawyers Bookcase, Royale Cherry Finish   3083.43 43168.02    Paid    Karumba 7   new
9   Howard Miller 13-3/4" Diameter Brushed Chrome Round Wall Clock  124.2   745.2   Paid    Kowanyama   3   new
```

I have to do the following things in it.
a) Linear Regression on Product Price and Monthly Sales and Plot a Graph
b) Plot Histogram over Geographic region and any other relationship
c) Find Min and Max from the Product Price and display some entities of the row

This is what i have done so far:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('furniture_Dataset.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
x_variables = dataframe[['Monthly Sales']]
y_variables = dataframe[['Product Price']]

#train model on data
body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_variables, y_variables)

#visualize results
plt.scatter(x_variables, y_variables)
plt.plot(x_variables, body_reg.predict(x_variables))
plt.show()
```

I haven't been able to do anthing apart from this.
this is not generating the graph as i'm getting the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 9: invalid start byte
```

For the rest part, I don't know anything.
Please Help Me.

Comment: Please post the entire code including import statements.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I think that posting the CSV file changed it, as it has very few commas. Can you link to the file?

Comment: For the assignment, we have to create a Dataset from scrap.
so you can't find this over internet

Comment: Are you certain the CSV format is correct? One way to test this is to only use the part of your code that reads in the file. If that works with no error, then test if the lines for x_variables and y_variables work without error. The idea is to run the program one line at a time. If the CSV file is not in the correct format, the above tests will fail and not the actual curve fitting part.

Comment: I created this file using Excel.
So, is that a problem.

Comment: I do not know. Try the tests I mentioned, that should tell you - no error should mean no problem.

Comment: Okay. I'll try them.